# Mi aplicación android no recibe notificaciones push desde PHP usando Firebase

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-messaging

Estoy ocupando Firebase Cloud Messaging para poder enviar notificaciones push a los dispositivos android que ya tengo identificados con su respectivo token. Tengo que aclarar que enviando pruebas de notificaciones push dentro del panel de Firebase éstas llegan correctamente.

El problema es que necesito enviar notificaciones push a estos dispositivos android con PHP. He logrado buscar algunas referencias en internet y hasta ahora veo que la respuesta de firebase a través de PHP es correcta ya que recibo, por ejemplo, respuestas como la siguiente:

```
{"multicast_id":63290198932730462,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1586129050019580%6a189d4df9fd7ecd"}]}
```

El detalle es que no están llegando los push a mi dispositivo android, el código PHP que estoy ocupando es una petición CURL:

```
<?php 

//Itrate token and store it in an array based on your dataset
$allTokens = array(
    'AQUI PONGO EL TOKEN DE MI DISPOSITIVO ANDROID'
);

 // This is a sample KEY
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AQUI PONGO EL API KEY DE MI CUENTA DE FIREBASE');

// Build your message as an array
$msg = array( 
            'title'         => "Payment Alert",
            'message'       => "You have received a test payment",
            'bigText'       => "You have received a test payment",
            "subText"       => "You have received a test payment",
            'summaryText'   => 'Alert for payment',
            'click_action'  => 'FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY',
            'vibrate'       => 300,
            'sound'         => 1,
);
$fields = array(
'registration_ids'  => $allTokens,  // multiple tokens will be available in array
'data'              => $msg
);
$headers = array(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);
if(!empty($allTokens)){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    var_dump($result);
}

?>
```

Nada de lo que he investigado me ha servido ya que sigo obteniendo la misma respuesta satisfactoria pero los push no están llegando a mi dispositivo cuando ocupo el código PHP. Espero puedan ayudarme a comprender por qué y cómo solucionarlo.

Gracias.

Comment: Hazle un var_dump($fiels) talves no este pasando ningún valor.

Comment: El código de tu php parece no tener errores, ¿ya te aseguraste que en realidad está correcto el Token del dispositivo?, ¿ya intentaste suscribirlos a un canal y enviar la notificación a ese canal?, en dado caso que no te resulte, prueba vinculando tu proyecto de nuevo a Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciona genial este codigo PHP con conexion a firebase:

```
function notify($to,$data){

    $api_key="API_FIREBASE";
    $url="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    $fields=json_encode(array('to'=>$to,'notification'=>$data));

  $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($fields));

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: key ='.$api_key;
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

 $to="TOKEN";

$data=array(
    'title'=>'BMG Innovation',
    'body'=>'Hi, you have an message. sinse php'
);

 notify($to,$data);
 echo "Notification Sent";
```

Comment: Saludos, es genial que quieras aportar, aunque seria mucho mejor si das una breve explicación de lo que hace tu código, considera que los usuarios nuevos con poca experiencia no entenderán tu respuesta, por favor lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así obtener tu primera medalla. ;)